# get data from just created node and pass it to url

Tags: drupal-6

I need to create an action that will be triggered after saving a certain content type node, I need the script to collect the zip location data from the node submited and submit it in to a view ulr

This is the form where the data is inserted.

```
<fieldset class="location">
  <legend>Location</legend>
  <div id="edit-locations-0-postal-code-wrapper" class="form-item">
    <label for="edit-locations-0-postal-code">
      Postal code:
      <span title="This field is required." class="form-required">*</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-text required" value="" size="16"
           id="edit-locations-0-postal-code" name="locations[0][postal_code]" 
           maxlength="16">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

This is the url where I want to insert the data

www.mysite.com/testview?distance[postal_code]=DATA_GOES_HERE

Comment: Is the user taken to a page at the DATA_GOES_HERE URL, or does this happen behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

You have to choices:

1) Installing the modules: [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) + [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules)

After you've enabled the modules follow these general steps:

- create a new rule
- event: after saving a new content
- add a condition: Node: Content has type (select the content type you wish this rule to apply to)
- add an action: System: Page redirect
- use the token replacements patterns to built the URL you wish to redirect (you should have access to all the node fields, including the CCK ones)

2) Implementing in your custom module [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6)

By implementing this hook you have access to the $node object and the second parameter passed to the hook is `$op` which tells you what action is being performed. In your case you might be interested in:

> "insert": The node has just been created (inserted in the database).

Your question is very similar to this one, so have a look: [Redirect a user after the node has been saved](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7138/redirect-a-user-after-the-node-has-been-saved)